# How to make auto uppercase when the user fill up a form through the system

Tags: php, html

i need some help, i want to make the words will auto capital letter/uppercase when the user fill up the form.. i tried using style="text-transform:uppercase" .. yes, the words will auto uppercase but in the database the words that saved through the form is still lowercase.. i don't know what's wrong.. can anybody help me? =')

```
<p>
    <span>NRIC/Passport No.</span>
    <input height="9" class="contact" type="text" name="no_ic" value="" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
</p>
<p>
    <span>Email Address</span>
    <input height="9" class="contact" type="text" name="admin_emeil" value="" />
</p>
<p>
    <span>Username</span>
    <input height="9" class="contact" type="text" name="username" value="" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done with PHP. I don't know how your PHP script is wired, but you can obtain the upper case `no_ic` using

```
$no_ic = strtoupper($_POST['no_ic']);  // ABCDE
```

Comment: heHe that's mine html coding.. this is my php coding 

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_admin (id, admin_name, admin_department, admin_position, admin_emeil, no_ic, username, pwd, level)
VALUES
('$_POST[id]','".strtoupper($_POST['admin_name']."','".strtoupper($_POST['admin_department']."','".strtoupper($_POST['admin_position']."','$_POST[admin_emeil]','".strtoupper($_POST['no_ic'])."','$_POST[username]','$_POST[pwd]','$_POST[level]')";